# how to create a cookie that checks to see if a user has been to my homepage

Tags: javascript, html

hi how do i create a cookie that checks to see if a user has been to my homepage first and if they havent redirects them to the homepage

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is not necessarily related to JavaScript. Would be better to do create and read the cookie on the server side.

Comment: havent tried anything yet. a beginner trying to find what is best to do really. basically if a user hasent been to my site before i want them to be redirected to my homepage first

Comment: What language and framework are you using? Most frameworks take care of cookie management for you.

Comment: i have just been doing a basic website in html

Answer (score 1):

This site has very good tutorial on cookie as well as example for creating and reading them
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

So on homepage you can create cookie using function createCookie(name,value,days) 
and read it on other pages using function readCookie(name)

So you can check value and redirect using   window.location = "http://www.any_url.com/"  in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do this on the server-side, since you wouldn't want the user to download the whole page, and *then* get redirected to download the home page too.

How to do it server-side depends on what language you are using.

On the other hand, you might not want to do this at all. What happens if the user doesn't accept cookies? Will he not be able to visit any page other than the home page on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Before telling you how to do this, I want to say ***don't do this***.  As a visitor, when I click a link to a specific page, I expect to end up on that page.  If I'm redirected to your homepage, I'll be frustrated and most likely leave your site – it's too much work to have to find the content I'm looking for after being redirected to a homepage I'm not interested in.

This happens to me all the time [when I click links to news articles on my phone](http://xkcd.com/869/).  Instead of the article I'm interested in, I get redirected to the site's mobile version homepage.  I promptly lose interest and close the tab.

So do your visitors a favor and don't break their expectations.  Make it easy for them to get to your homepage *if they want to*, but don't force it.

So that said, let's call this an academic exercise.  Using [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

**Homepage:** `$.cookie('seenhp', true, { expires: 365 });`

**Other pages:** `if (!$.cookie('seenhp')) location.assign('/index.html');`

Comment: josh i think this is the kind of thing i have been looking for do i just paste the text on the appropriate pages

Comment: any particular place it would need to go? also many thanks for your help