# Cookie to check if user has been before if not then redirected to home page

Tags: php, cookies

Hi 
I’m trying to use the following cookie to force users to go to my homepage first no matter what link they come to me from (I know a lot of people frown upon this but it’s something i wish to do) if they haven't been to my homepage before:

I have the following code on my home page between the “head” tags:

```
$.cookie(“seenhp”, true, { expires: 365 });
```

And the following code on every other page between the “head” tags again:

```
if (!$.cookie(“seenhp”)) location.assign(“/index.php”);
```

It doesn’t seem to be working am i missing something very obvious?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a cookie that checks to see if a user has been to my homepage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018983/how-to-create-a-cookie-that-checks-to-see-if-a-user-has-been-to-my-homepage)

Comment: I don't know what language this is you're writing your code in, but it's most definitely not PHP.  PHP code doesn't look like this.  You should never force your users to do things unless you can't avoid it.  You'll only succeed in alienating users.  It's also extremely search-engine hostile, as any attempt Google makes to crawl your site will only show the home page.  You could prehaps display an invitation to visit the home page if the cookie isn't set, but forcing the user to the home page for any reason other than needing to be logged in to use the site is right out.

Answer (score 2):

you tagged this with PHP, but I cant see any PHP code here. This looks more like jquery?
Have you included jquery?

Well the PHP way would be

```
setcookie("seenhp", "seenhp");
```

and

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["seenhp"])){
    header("Location: http://home.page/");
    die();
}
```

Not meaning to be offinsive, but please try to understand what you're doing.
Reading the other thread, i guess you don't use:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: no offence taken, I have been trying to get my head around this for a couple of weeks now and just keep drawing blanks (still very much a beginner, but learning). thanks for your help though it is much appreciated ill give this a try and see how it goes.